# how to use eager execution to save and restore in TensorFlow？

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, eager-execution

We always use `tf.train.Saver()` to save and restore weights, like in [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) example.

But how to use eager execution to save? how to change the following example?

Another question, is it a good idea to use eager?

I found `tf.contrib.eager.Saver` [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/eager/Saver), but it says,

> "Saver's name-based checkpointing strategy is fragile".

What does it mean?

```
# Create some variables.
v1 = tf.get_variable("v1", shape=[3], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)
v2 = tf.get_variable("v2", shape=[5], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)

inc_v1 = v1.assign(v1+1)
dec_v2 = v2.assign(v2-1)

# Add an op to initialize the variables.
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Add ops to save and restore all the variables.
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# Later, launch the model, initialize the variables, do some work, and save the
# variables to disk.
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op)
  # Do some work with the model.
  inc_v1.op.run()
  dec_v2.op.run()
  # Save the variables to disk.
  save_path = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
  print("Model saved in path: %s" % save_path)
```

Comment: Could you find out how to save and restore in eager execution? Thanks!

Comment: did u get the answer?